# How to perform caesar cipher logic using random key?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to take user input for message. Then I generate a random key using `random` package in python.
But how to shift each letter in message using key's *ascii* value to produce output as string only?
Example :

```
message = hi   
random key generated = bi  
encrypted message = "something in alphabets only like xh or mo."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the objectype dictionary to map each character to another so that you create a new alphabet, and the loop through the dictionary and replace them using the dictionary

```
stringa = input()
swapa = {"A":"Q", "B":"A","C":"L"...}
for i in swapa:
    stringa = stringa.replace(i,swapa[i])
print(stringa)
```

you could also take it a step fourther and encryot and decrypt using a keyword

```
ite = int(input())
    for itar in range(ite):
    keyw = list(input())
    # removes dublicates and keep order
    rem = set()
    for i in keyw:
        if keyw.count(i) > 1:
            rem.add(i)
    for i in rem:
        keyw= keyw[::-1]
        keyw.remove(i)
        keyw= keyw[::-1]
    keyw = "".join(keyw)
    # sets up alfabet
    linaalfa = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    linaalfa += " "*(len(keyw)-len(linaalfa)%len(keyw)) # adds spaces on the last line
    linaalf = "".join([i for i in linaalfa if i not in keyw]) # removes dublicates
    linaalf1 = [keyw]+[linaalf[x:x+len(keyw)] for x in range(0,len(linaalf),len(keyw))]
    # alfa order find
    order = dict()
    for w,i in enumerate(sorted(keyw)):
        order[keyw.index(i)] = w
    # order in alfa ordder
    orderalfa = ["".join([i[q] for i in linaalf1]) for q in range(len(keyw))] # now read by column
    temp = [""]*len(orderalfa)
    for w,i in enumerate(orderalfa):
        temp[order[w]] = i
    orderalfa = temp
    orderalfa = "".join([x.strip() for x in orderalfa])
    # relate to base alfabet
    translate = dict()
    encrypt = dict()
    for w,i in enumerate(orderalfa):
        translate[i] = linaalfa[w]
        encrypt[linaalfa[w]] = i
    # trans late message
    lina = input().split()
    outa = list()
    for i in lina:
        temp = ""
        for q in i:
            temp += translate[q]
        outa.append(temp)
    print(" ".join(outa))
```

here it takes the input

```
n # number of quaries
keyword
string that need to be operated
```

the last bit however is set to decrypt the message if you want it to encrupt it you need to replace the line

```
temp += translate[q]
```

to

```
temp += encrypt[q]
```

This takes a keyword and

1. removes dublicate letters in said keyword
2. Set the keyword in front of the an alfabet(a normal one)
3. and splits the alfabet up in peaces the same length as the keyword
4. places them above each other
5. orderes them in column order based on if the keyword's letter were written in alfabetical order
6. takes each coloumn and creats a new alphabet based on the each coloum put continualy after each other
7. this new alphabet now works as the new alphabet

for example if the beginning of the new alphabet were "HGJ" than A would be H, and B would be G and J would be C.

This is stil only a monoalphabetical encryption though.